# What version of mongodb was full $text query operator introduced?

Tags: mongodb

Stupid question, right? But the official docs for 'text index' say:

```
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/
Text Indexes
New in version 2.4.
To perform queries that access the text index, use the $text query operator.
```

Whereas if you click on the help for searching the index you created with the $text operator, it reads:

```
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text
$text
New in version 2.6.
```

Seems to be 2.4 but still having problems wiht it.

Comment: They're two different things. See this quote "`text` indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements. To perform queries that access the text index, use the `$text` query operator."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having similar problems recently until upgrading to 2.6. In 2.4, text indexing was introduced as an experimental feature that had to be explicitly enabled, see this [Mongo 2.4 text article](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/40513621310/mongodb-text-search-experimental-feature-in-mongodb). So, it was possible to add a text index, after enabling text search, but actually doing text search required using:

```
db.runCommand("text":{search:searchTerm});
```

The current syntax:

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:searchTerm}});
```

appears to have been added in 2.5.5, if you look at the [MongoDB JIRA bug entitled: *Integrate text search into normal query system*](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9063).

I believe that the docs are somewhat confusing in this regard as they seem to suggest that enabling text search is all you need to do in 2.4.

Comment: So pymongo seems to support it. This worked:  db.collection.find( {'$text': {'$search': u'school'}} ) when the fulltext index ('$**',"text") was created. But was confused about why bother saying it is supported if they're not sure if it is. ALso - does 2.4 do word stemming too?

Comment: I didn't try in pymongo, I was using the 2.4.5 console, but I kept getting an error about invalid syntax near search or some such -- I have removed 2.4, so can't get exact error. According to this, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-380, stemming should be included in 2.4. I often find the docs to be a bit confusing in Mongo and the bug reports/source code are the best way to find out what/when something happened. BTW, your profile is really interesting. I worked for a few weeks on a GIS project in Ghana once, which was pretty eye opening. What you have done in West Africa is awesome.

Comment: Thanks John! my latest projects are hosted at storylearning.org or globalgiving.org/storytelling for more context.